# 30K recommended service for honda civic 2013

Tags: honda, scheduled-maintenance, service

I have Honda Civic 2013 and have 37K miles on odometer. Haven't done 30K recommended service but i scheduled appointment with dealership. The detail service list is

- 4 Wheel Brake Service
- Air Filter Replacement
- Alignment Check
- Brake 4 Wheel Inspection
- Fuel Injector Cleaner
- Multi Point Inspection
- Replace automatic transmission fluid
- Replace brake fluid
- Replace cabin air filter
- Replace engine coolant
- Replace engine oil
- Rotate tires
- Throttle Body Clean
- Wash and Vac
- Wiper Blades (2)

The estimated cost is 425$ from dealership. Do you think if this is really required and the cost is reasonable? i also checked with automd and couldn't find few things in list.

Comment: If they actually do all the work listed; then it is worth the price. My bet is they are going to skimp on things like alignment check. They will probably checks for symptoms such as uneven tire wear, but won't actually do an alignment check for example.

Comment: If the vehicle is still in warranty and you want to maintain the warranty, you'll want to do the recommended services. This doesn't mean you have to do it at the dealership (aka: *stealership*). You can get the work done anywhere ... just keep the records.

Comment: @Paulster2 Vehicle is not in warranty (37000 miles now). I am thinking about having oil change at a local and have them inspect vehicle in detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My list would not include: Fuel injection cleaner; use Top Tier certified fuel instead. Engine Coolant, too early for the new, better coolant chemistry. Throttle body clean, needed only if symptoms develop. The transmission fluid change interval sparks a debate in the repair industry. I err on the side of caution and change it every 30k miles with OEM fluid.